# Grid and Graticule in QGIS Print Composer in QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer, grids-graticules, qgis-2.8

I'd like to add a grid in the print composer. The problem is there is no visible option like it was in previous version. I mean I'm looking for an option "Show grid?" like in the picture below. I can't see this in 2.8.

How do I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Under the map's Item Properties panel, look for the "Grids" section. Expand that out and click the green "+" button to add a new grid (you can now have multiple grids per map):

[image]