# How to put graticule on QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, grids-graticules

[image]

How to put coordinates on grid using WGS 84 as the CRS.

Comment: Which software do you use? What have you tried?

Comment: You could use a pen. Or give us some more details, e.g. the software you're working with, that you want to achieve this in the print composer etc.

Comment: WGS84 isn't a CRS

Answer (score 2):

MS Paint works well if you don't know which software was used to create a map.

If you are in ArcMap, there are [some instructions here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/adding-a-graticule.htm).

If you are using QGIS, here is an [example that might help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192417/positioning-of-graticule-labels-in-qgis-2-14-1)